# django is m2m relationship really necessary?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have two models like this.

```py
class Channel(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'channel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'channels'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['box', 'name'], name='channel_box_name_idx'),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_next_position(self):
        aggregate = self.box.channels.aggregate(models.Max('position'))
        return (aggregate['position__max'] or -1) + 1

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            # we insert the object's position if
            # it hasn't been created yet. We need to do
            # this explicitly because django doesn't
            # allow more than one auto-field
            self.position = self.get_next_position()
            super(Channel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.box.channels.add(self)
        super(Channel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)])
    box = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.Box', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [name, box]

class Box(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'box'
        verbose_name_plural = 'boxes'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['owner'], name='box_owner_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['owner', 'name'], name='box_name_owner_idx'),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    objects = models.Manager()
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons/', storage=DefaultStorage)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)])
    owner = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channels = models.ManyToManyField('api_backend.Channel', related_name='box_channels')

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [name, owner]
```

Channel has an attribute `box`. And box has a m2m field `channels`. so in this type of relationship, whenever I create the channel with the box, I need to add the same to the box's m2m field `channels`. Is something like this really necessary? Like I need to have an extra table for the m2m field `channels` and even If I don't have it, I can access the same by doing `box.channel_set`

So, would there be any changes in the performance? Should I change my models structure?
can someone please help me?

Comment: Can a channel have multiple boxes? If yes then a m2m is appropriate and the `ForeignKey` should be removed, if no then you should remove the m2m and use `box.channel_set`. You can add `related_name='channels'` to the `ForeignKey` to change `channel_set` to `channels` on Box instances

Comment: a channel can have only one box

Comment: can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Happy to help. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can a channel have multiple boxes? If yes then a `ManyToManyField` is appropriate and the `ForeignKey` should be removed

If a `ManyToManyField` is not necessary since a `Channel` can only have one related `Box` then the `ManyToManyField` should be removed and the related accessor `channel_set` should be used

If you wish to have an attribute on `Box` instances named `channels` instead of `channel_set` that can be used to access any related `Channel`s you can provide `related_name` to the `ForeignKey`

```
class Channel(BaseModel):
    ...
    box = models.ForeignKey('api_backend.Box', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='channels')
    ...
```

Comment: Will there be any compromise on performance??

Comment: When accessing a foreign key multiple times in the same queryset you should use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and when accessing the reverse you should use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)